# TeeChart does not accept UnNamed or Unknown colors

Tags: c#-4.0, teechart

When I apply color on TeeChart other than a named or known color it is shown as transparent. This applies to axis, series, labels, and gridlines.

```
CyChartControl.Header.Font.Color = Color.FromArgb(((System.Byte)(A)),((System.Byte)(R)),((System.Byte) (G)), ((System.Byte)(B)));
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine for me here:

```
tChart1.Header.Font.Color = Color.FromArgb(200, 200, 50, 150);
```

What TeeChart .NET version are you using?
It would be helpful if you could send us a simple example project we can run as-is to reproduce the problem here.
You can send your files to "info at steema dot com"

Comment: Thanks There is programming bug I removed it and no bug in Teechart